# Get notified when workstation gets locked

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

On Windows system pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will lock the workstation.
Is there a way within XUL addon detect when workstation is being locked down? I could probably detect pressing this key combination, but it would only work if XUL application in focus.

There is a [sleep_notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Observer_Notifications#Computer_sleep_and_wake) available for when computer is going into sleep mode (or waking up). I can't find any information about locking workstation.

Comment: Only option is js-ctypes. But did you read the blog about WebExtensions? They are going to disallow everything except webextensions by end of 2017 - webext has an api though that lets you know when the screensaver comes on i think. With webextension, only way to do this is via native messaging.

Comment: Thunderbird, Waterfox and Palemoon will continue use XUL, so this is still viable.

js-ctypes would mean external libriaries and not system-to-system compatible?

And what is "native messaging"?

Comment: js-ctypes is system to system compatible, but not platform to platform. So you have to do it once for mac, linux, and windows. Native messaging is similar except that instead of js-ctypes you use actual C++ or whatever or even Javascript (Electron app) and then this can do anything and you can connect this to your extension via native messaging. Issue is, that binary (Electron or C++ app) you have to host that on your website and your users now have to install your addon from AMO, then also go and install your app store. One option is dont use AMO and have he app side load the addon.

Comment: I think I found a way to test if workstation is locked or not by using
OpenDesktop (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684303(v=vs.85).aspx) and SwitchDesktop 

If only someone could show me how to execute this from js-ctypes, I believe I can figure out the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using js-ctypes (tested on Windows 10):

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
var lib           = ctypes.open("user32.dll"),
    openDesktop   = lib.declare("OpenDesktopA", ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.uint32_t, ctypes.char.ptr, ctypes.uint32_t, ctypes.bool, ctypes.uint32_t),
    switchDesktop = lib.declare("SwitchDesktop", ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.bool, ctypes.uint32_t),
    closeDesktop  = lib.declare("CloseDesktop", ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.bool, ctypes.uint32_t),
    desktop       = openDesktop("Default", 0, 0, 0x0100),
    isUnLocked    = switchDesktop(desktop);

console.log(isUnLocked);//result false = locked, true = unlocked

closeDesktop(desktop);
lib.close();
```